# PayPal - Client Authentication failed - Switch to Live Mode

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

i have build a simple shop and want to use my PayPal Plus Account, so users can pay per PayPal, Credi Card and Bank Account.
In Sandbox Mode everything works perfect, but when i switch to Live Mode an use the Live credentials for my app i got this:

`{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"}`

I have tried 3 different Apps now, but nothing worked.

In my developer account is no error message or warning that i cant use this or something like that.

Do i have to make an review process or something like that to use it in Live Mode?

**Update**

I have used the worng mode in the PHP SDK. Now i get no error from the PHP SDK, but the Javascript SDK which schould build the Paywall gives me an 403 Error.

Comment: I think I had something similar, it was solved when I tried it from Incognito tab - It was a caching issue on paypal side in my case

Comment: good idea but no that does not solve my problem. Same error

Comment: Hi, I used the instructions to go live https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Going-Live but I still get the error. Any insight?